# How to bind tree view with XMLdatasource dynamically in c#

Tags: xml, elements-xml, splistitemcollection

I have a scenario where I have a SPListItemCollection of SharePoint 2013 and I have to bind tree view with XMLDataSource. I have to add nodes to XML and iterate to add child nodes also but all these things has to be performed on run time only. Below is my .ascx code where I have both the controls( tree view and XMLDataSource):

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvKnowledgeTypeDetail" runat="server" ShowLines="true" DataSourceID="XMLDataSource1">
</asp:TreeView>   
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XMLDataSource1" runat="server" EnableCaching="false" />
```

and now the code to get collection of documents from a document library:

```
SPListItemCollection itemColl = null;
string strQuery = string.Empty;
List<string> lstViewFieldColumns = new List<string>();
lstViewFieldColumns.Add("CoverageGroupLookup");
lstViewFieldColumns.Add("SectorLookup");
lstViewFieldColumns.Add("KnowledgeTypeLookup");

strQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='KnowledgeTypeLookup' /><Value Type='Lookup'>Research Manuals</Value></Eq></Where>";

using (KnowledgeDocumentBLL knowledgeDocumentBLL = new KnowledgeDocumentBLL())
{
    itemColl = knowledgeDocumentBLL.GetKnowledgeDocumentCollection(strDocumentLibraryName, strQuery, lstViewFieldColumns);
}

List<string> distinctCoverageGrp = (from SPListItem items in itemColl
                            select items["CoverageGroupLookup"].ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
foreach (string coverageGrp in distinctCoverageGrp)
{
    //add to XML (How?)
}
```

Now, I have a generic list where I have distinct "CoverageGroup" and I have to add it to XML within a foreach loop and then get distinct of "Sectors" and add sectors to specific Coverage group parent node in XML.If any one have any idea that how to add nodes to XML and then bind it then please provide me the steps as I am new for tree view.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the above issue  and now i am able to bind my tree view control to xml data source. Below is the code:

```
private void BindTreeView()
    {

        SPListItemCollection itemColl = null;
        string strQuery = string.Empty;
        List<string> lstViewFieldColumns = new List<string>();
        lstViewFieldColumns.Add("DocumentTitle");
        lstViewFieldColumns.Add("CoverageGroupLookup");
        lstViewFieldColumns.Add("SectorLookup");
        lstViewFieldColumns.Add("KnowledgeTypeLookup");

        strQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='KnowledgeTypeLookup' /><Value Type='Lookup'>Research Manuals</Value></Eq></Where>";
        using (KnowledgeDocumentBLL knowledgeDocumentBLL = new KnowledgeDocumentBLL())
        {
            itemColl = knowledgeDocumentBLL.GetKnowledgeDocumentCollection(strDocumentLibraryName, strQuery, lstViewFieldColumns);
        }
        List<string> distinctCoverageGrpList = (from SPListItem items in itemColl
                                                select items["CoverageGroupLookup"].ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<KnowledgeType Name='CompanyProfile'></KnowledgeType>");

        foreach (string coverageGrp in distinctCoverageGrpList)
        {
            SPFieldLookupValue coverageGrpLookup = new SPFieldLookupValue(Convert.ToString(coverageGrp));
            XmlNode rootNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("KnowledgeType");
            XmlNode parentNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "CoverageGroupLookup", "");
            XmlAttribute xmlAttributeName = doc.CreateAttribute("Name");
            xmlAttributeName.Value = coverageGrpLookup.LookupValue;
            XmlAttribute xmlAttributeValue = doc.CreateAttribute("Value");
            xmlAttributeValue.Value = coverageGrpLookup.LookupId.ToString();
            parentNode.Attributes.Append(xmlAttributeName);
            parentNode.Attributes.Append(xmlAttributeValue);

            ////Append Sector node to CoverageGroup
            List<string> distinctSectorList = (from SPListItem items in itemColl
                                               where items["CoverageGroupLookup"].ToString() == coverageGrp
                                               select items["SectorLookup"].ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
            foreach (string sector in distinctSectorList)
            {
                SPFieldLookupValue sectorLookup = new SPFieldLookupValue(Convert.ToString(sector));
                XmlNode childNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "SectorLookup", "");
                XmlAttribute xmlChildAttributeName = doc.CreateAttribute("Name");
                xmlChildAttributeName.Value = sectorLookup.LookupValue;
                XmlAttribute xmlChildAttributeValue = doc.CreateAttribute("Value");
                xmlChildAttributeValue.Value = sectorLookup.LookupId.ToString();
                childNode.Attributes.Append(xmlChildAttributeName);
                childNode.Attributes.Append(xmlChildAttributeValue);
                parentNode.AppendChild(childNode);
            }
            rootNode.AppendChild(parentNode);
        }
        XMLDataSource1.Data = doc.InnerXml;
        XMLDataSource1.DataBind();
        tvKnowledgeTypeDetail.DataBind();
 }
```

and source code to bind it is as below:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvKnowledgeTypeDetail" runat="server"  ShowLines="true" DataSourceID="XMLDataSource1" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvKnowledgeTypeDetail_SelectedNodeChanged" OnTreeNodeDataBound="tvKnowledgeTypeDetail_TreeNodeDataBound"  >
    <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#DD5555" />
    <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px"
        NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="5px"></NodeStyle>
    <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px"
        ForeColor="#DD5555" />
    <DataBindings>
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="CoverageGroupLookup" ValueField="Value" TextField="Name" Depth="1" />
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="SectorLookup" ValueField="Value" TextField="Name"  Depth="2" />
    </DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XMLDataSource1" runat="server"  EnableCaching="false"/>
```

Now, one more issue is that how can i make a tree node clickable at runt time only if it has no child node (if the node is leaf node). I have tried with the below code to test with the tool tip attribute and its working fine:

```
protected void TreeNode_Clickable(TreeNode node)
    {
        if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            node.ToolTip = "Leaf Node";
        }
        else
        {
            node.ToolTip = "Parent Node";
        }

    }
```

I want to make a node clickable if its a leaf node  only otherwise not clickable. If anyone has did it before, then please suggest.